# multi radio buttons transformed into a radio button with css?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I want After click on the radio,
Radio-selected that background color is yellow putting background label, with use of css no js.
how is it?

Example of myself: http://jsfiddle.net/DVJmS/6/
Example of ui: http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/radio.html -> I not want use of plugin this is only a example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Volia](http://jsfiddle.net/DVJmS/30/)

What you need to do is:

1. wrap each `<input /><label></label>` in a  `<div>`
2. give `input[type="radio”]` a width and height of 0px
3. Then add this rule to your css `:checked ~ label {
   background: #f00;
   }`

What that last one does is says if there’s a sibling of mine that is checked preceding me then make me have a background of `#f00`. Just change the alignment and colors to fit your site.

Also, you should **never** give two elements the same ID. If you want to be able to select two elements at once **always** uses classes.

Comment: Oh, quick note: If you’re not going to have any HTML element in between your radio button and the label for it, it’d be much better to use `:checked + label { background: #f00; }` instead of `:checked ~ label { background: #f00; }`. The `+` is only for immediately preceding siblings (instead of *any* preceding sibling), but it (`+`) was available in CSS2 instead of CSS3.